# multer file upload doesn't show the path where file is stored

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using node, express and multer to upload files in angular application while having mongoDB for the database. When I'm uploading a file, although it's getting uploaded in the destination folder called uploads which I declared as static in my index.js, it's path where the file is saved is not shown in the database and remains blank as a default value. Below is a snap of my database when the form is created and the image is also uploaded but the imagePath field where the location should be remains blank

```
{
    "title": "title to check file upload second time",
    "description": "checking file upload check",
    "bodyHtml": "",
    "views": 0,
    "isPublished": true,
    "category": "Drama",
    "author": "",
    "imagePath": "",
    "_id": "5e399bd4de5df134604a662f",
    "blogId": "ZSiEu37z",
    "created": "2020-02-04T16:29:08.000Z",
    "lastModified": "2020-02-04T16:29:08.000Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

multer settings on the controller:

```
const multer = require('multer')

 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
     destination: function(req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, './uploads/')
     },
     filename: function(req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname)
     }
 })

 const upload = multer({storage: storage})
let setRouter = (app) => {
    let baseUrl = appConfig.apiVersion+'/blogs';

app.post(baseUrl+'/create', upload.single('imagePath'), (req, res) => {
    var today = time.now()
    let blogId = shortid.generate()
    let newBlog = new BlogModel({

        blogId: blogId,
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        imagePath: req.body.imagePath

    }) // end new blog model

    newBlog.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.send(err)
        } else {
            res.send(result)

        }
    }) // end new blog save
})
```

blog model

```
// importing mongoose module
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
// import schema 
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let blogSchema = new Schema(
    {
        blogId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            index: true
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        imagePath: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    }
)

mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

inside controller function while saving the json object use req.file.path instead of req.body.imagePath as a value of imagePath

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of the file that will be used in your upload folder directory before upload the file, just save that name in mongo

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html

Comment: I'm using the same key called imagePath all accross the application..but getting blank while creating

Comment: please attach your BlogModel

Comment: attached as requested. please check

Comment: @surjendu_dey is correct, try debugging to confirm the field you want to save is not empty

Answer (score 0):

Inside controller ,in imagePath req object write REQ.FILE.PATH insted of REQ.BODY.imagePath...{note: for "REQ.FILE.PATH" you dont have to import path modeul... }

and that path coming from your app.js file where you use path.join(__dirname, 'foldername');

Comment: you need to encapsulate your code in a code snippet